# Text box value don't become negative values

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     var label = parseInt($("#label1").html());
     alert(label);
     $("#Incre").click(function() {
         $("#number").val(parseInt($("#number").val()) + label);
     });
     $("#Decre").click(function() {
         $("#number").val(parseInt($("#number").val()) - label);
     });
 });
```

```html
<label id='label1'>50</label>
<input id='number' value=0></input>
<button  id='Incre'>Incre</button>
<button  id='Decre'>Decre</button>
```

I have this code it's working. but when textbox value is Zero . if i click on the decrement button the textbox value is become negative values. how to control this one.

Comment: *if i click on the decrement button the textbox value is become negitive values. how to control this one.* ? can OP explain clearly?

Comment: You need to check the current value then increment or decrement accordingly.

Comment: use `Math.max(0, finalValue)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     var label = parseInt($("#label1").html());
     alert(label);
     $("#Incre").click(function() {
         $("#number").val(parseInt($("#number").val()) + label);
     });
     $("#Decre").click(function() {
         var final_number = parseInt($("#number").val()) - label;
         if (final_number >= 0) {
             $("#number").val(parseInt($("#number").val()) - label);
         }

     });
 });
</script>
<label id='label1'>50</label>
<input id='number' value=0></input>
<button  id='Incre'>Incre</button>
<button  id='Decre'>Decre</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check value on update, if value is less than `0` then set as previous value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var label = parseInt($("#label1").html()),
    $num = $("#number");
  $("#Incre").click(function() {
    $num.val(function(i, v) {
      return parseInt(v) + label
    });
  });
  $("#Decre").click(function() {
    $dec = $(this);
    $num.val(function(i, v) { // use callback to update based on old value
      var res = parseInt(v) - label; // get the decremented value
      return res < 0 ? v : res; // return old value if -ve value reached
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id='label1'>50</label>
<input id='number' value=0></input>
<button id='Incre'>Incre</button>
<button id='Decre'>Decre</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `Math.max()`.

`$("#number").val(Math.max(0, parseInt($("#number").val())-label));`